# How to fix IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning

I tried a lot to use YOLOv3 to input mp4 file but always I got errors while testing the model with video file, especially this error :

```
invalid index to scalar variable
```

I really need help to fix this issue or if there is a better code structure to test yolov3 with video file

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2

# initialize minimum probability to eliminate weak predictions
p_min = 0.5

# threshold when applying non-maxia suppression
thres = 0.

# 'VideoCapture' object and reading video from a file
video = cv2.VideoCapture('parking1.mp4')

# Preparing variable for writer
# that we will use to write processed frames
writer = None

# Preparing variables for spatial dimensions of the frames
h, w = None, None

# Create labels into list
with open('coco.names') as f:
    labels = [line.strip() for line in f]
# Initialize colours for representing every detected object
colours = np.random.randint(0, 255, size=(len(labels), 3), dtype='uint8')

# Loading trained YOLO v3 Objects Detector
# with the help of 'dnn' library from OpenCV
# Reads a network model stored in Darknet model files.
network = cv2.dnn.readNetFromDarknet('yolov3.cfg',
                                     'yolov3.weights')

# Getting only output layer names that we need from YOLO(ERRORRRRRRRRRR HEREEE) 
ln = network.getLayerNames()
ln = [ln[i[0] - 1] for i in network.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]

# Defining loop for catching frames
while True:
    ret, frame = video.read()
    if not ret:
        break

    # Getting dimensions of the frame for once as everytime dimensions will be same
    if w is None or h is None:
        # Slicing and get height, width of the image
        h, w = frame.shape[:2]

    # frame preprocessing for deep learning
    blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(frame, 1 / 255.0, (416, 416),
                                 swapRB=True, crop=False)
```

Here is the erorr:
[image]

Comment: Can you give us the whole error please?

Comment: this is the whole error :: IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable  (and there is a highlight in this line)  ln = [ln[i[0] - 1] for i in network.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]

Comment: No like the whole traceback and everything.

Comment: I posted an answer with a screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the error is occurring when you are trying to `getLayerNames()` from your defined `network`. Basically, you are trying to access an element of a scalar variable as if it were an array or list. But in fact, `getUnconnectedOutLayers()` outputs the position of the layers as an `ndarray` of 1-D shape `(1,)`.

So, to make it short, even though it is a `tuple`, treat it as `int` for CPU w/CUDA. Replace this line that you have:

```
ln = [ln[i[0] - 1] for i in network.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]
```

simply to this instead:

```
ln = [ln[i- 1] for i in network.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]
```

Hope this resolves your issue. If so, please mark this response as the answer.